# return statement in recursive function

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am trying to write a recursive function for linear search in an array which also returns the first index at which the element is found.

```
int linearSearch(int *A, int size, int val)
{
    if(size>0)
    {
        if(*A==val)
        {
            cout<<val<<" is found in the array!";
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            linearSearch(A+1,size-1,val);
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<val<<" is not there in the array!";
        return -1;
    }
}
```

However, when I am trying to catch the valued returned in the main function, value of size is returned instead of -1 in the case when the element is not present in the array. I am not able to figure out why is that happening.

Comment: `linearSearch(A+1,size-1,val);` is a bug

Comment: Thanks for your reply @drescherjm. It should be `return linearSearch(A+1,size-1,val);` , right?

Comment: There are other problems in addition to that. Why is `i` a global variable? That will cause you issues if calling more than once unless you reset `i`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I added a couple of comments in the code so you can understand it better.

```
/* i is the initial position. When you are making a call to linearSearch it should be set to 0 */
int linearSearch(int *A, int size, int val, int i)
{
    /* When you reach end of the array and havent found value, then return -1 */
    /* Every recursive function should have an exit condition */
    if(i == size)
        return -1;

    /* when we found a value return the index */
    if (A[i] == val)
        return i;
    else
        /* If not then move to the next value in the array by incrementing index and recurse */
        return linearSearch(A, size, val, i + 1);
}
```